# IIS Url Rewrite Module redirect url that does not exit to one that exists

Tags: asp.net, url, redirect, iis-7.5, iis-8.5

Is there a way to redirect to a URL when a user inputs a URL in the browser that does not have an actual address but is under said domain, using the URLRewrite Module in IIS 7.5 or 8.5?

example:
https://examplesite.com/test

redirected to: 
https://examplesite.com/site/home.aspx

```
   <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="redirectURL" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^.*(/test)$" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://examplesite.com/site/home.aspx" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Every entry I have tried using this module does not seem to work for this scenario.

Comment: I don't think the module can do that. There is no way of knowing if the matched url exitsts or not. It only rewrites. The answer of @Mike is can work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if you can do it under IIS Rewrite rules but you can define custom error handling

```
<customErrors defaultRedirect="ErrorPage.aspx" mode="On">       
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="https://examplesite.com/site/home.aspx" />
</customErrors>
```